# Android Error on delete from database (Could not execute method of the activity)

Tags: android

I'm building a task list app.  For each task, a RelativeLayout is created, within which is a CheckBox and a TextView with the name of the task.  Then it's added to a pre-existing LinearLayout.  That part all works.

I added a 'Delete Task' ImageButton that calls the method deleteTask(View view).  deleteTask() which deletes the task from the database.  When I try to run I get **"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity"** along with a bunch of other errors.

```
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    ... 11 more
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at com.rook.todolist.MainActivity.deleteTask(MainActivity.java:177)
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    ... 14 more
```

Here's my code.  Tried to include what I thought is relevant, obviously can include more if need be.

**deleteTask()** called by ImageButton :

```
public void deleteTask (View view) {

    // instantiate dbhandler
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    // get tasks
    List<Task> tasks = db.getAllTasks();

    for(Task t : tasks) {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(t.getID() + 10000);
        if(cb.isChecked()) { db.deleteTask(t); }
    }

    buildTaskList();

}//end deleteTask()
```

When I create the CheckBoxes, they needed to have an id that I could reference for LayoutParams, so I set their id to be 10,000 + the id of the task.  Just something that's easily rememberable.

buildTaskList() just removes all views from the master LinearLayout and rebuilds them based on tasks in the database.

**deleteTask(Task task)** called if CheckBox is checked.

```
// Deleting single task
public void deleteTask (Task task) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_TASKS, KEY_ID + " =?", new String[] { String.valueOf(task.getID()) });
}
```

*The delete operation is still performed.* When I reload the app, the task that was to be deleted is gone.  Also, I tested deleteTask() when I first created it and it worked.

**Edit**
As many pointed out, the line `findViewById(t.getID() + 10000);` was returning an ImageView not a checkbox.  But I put in log statements to spit out the ids both in the method where they are created and in the deleteTask() method *and the ids are the same!*  Do the ids assigned to views change or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as in log :

> ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.CheckBox

means you are trying to cast ImageView to Checkbox . change your code as :

```
for(Task t : tasks) {
        View view = (View) findViewById(t.getID() + 10000);

        if( view instanceof CheckBox ) {
          CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
          if(cb.isChecked()) { db.deleteTask(t); }
    }

    }
```

Comment: No more error, but now the task isn't deleted from the database.  Obviously since the error was around ImageView vs CheckBox the if( view instanceof CheckBox ) code is preventing the db.deleteTask operation.  But why was it being deleted before?

Comment: @MarcSchlossberg : this is right code to get View instance type but u can also try as  `View view =context.findViewById(t.getID() + 10000);`

Answer (score 2):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox
    at com.rook.todolist.MainActivity.deleteTask(MainActivity.java:177)
```

The id you use in `findViewById()` refers to an ImageView, which you cannot cast to a CheckBox. Double check your View ids.

```
// This returns an ImageView...
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(t.getID() + 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here

```
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox
01-16 13:15:48.975: E/AndroidRuntime(16881):    at com.rook.todolist.MainActivity.deleteTask(MainActivity.java:177)
```

you are **trying to cast ImageView to a checkBox**, most probably in below line of code

```
 CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(t.getID() + 10000);
```